# nemo desktop icons on elementary os

Tags: desktop

I have installed `nemo` file manager and wanted to enable desktop icons.

As you can see on the screenshot the desktop is looking like a normal window.

So how to fix that? I'm running elementary OS Freya.

[image: nemo as desktop manager screenshot]

Comment: Looks like your desktop is enable. Can you be a bit clearer of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I thought it's clear! you can see that the desktop is looking like a normal window and not full screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a decision by elementary os to enable client-side decorations which affect windows not aware of that. See [GTK+ Incorrect Window Size](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3799/1239)

This is tested to work for Freya in VBox:

```
GTK_CSD="" nemo
```

So modify exec line in the autostart file 
`/etc/xdg/autostart/nemo-autostart.desktop` , as below:

```
Exec=sh -c "GTK_CSD=\"\" nemo -n"
```

or

```
Exec=sh -c "GTK_CSD='' nemo -n"
```

[image]

Comment: wonderful! it worked like charm! 
but I changed the desktop file to: 
sh -c "GTK_CSD="" nemo" %U 
and autostart desktop: 
sh -c "killall nemo && GTK_CSD="" nemo" 
and still getting that window on login

Comment: @Naheel, good, I will check where the cmd of nemo for session start. So we can change it without that kill cmd.

Comment: @Naheel, your issue is with the `""` escaping, see my edit, please if it works for you, check the accept flag, see https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to:

   ```
   /usr/share/applications/nemo.desktop
   ```
2. For this you need administrator privilege, and change:

   ```
   Exec = nemo --no-desktop %U
   ```
3. Also check in `~/.local/share/applications/` folder. If there is nemo file, make the same changes.

Comment: no difference at all

Comment: You can try to run this command in your terminal: gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Elementary and wanted my beloved OS X-Desktop back, so I tried this.
Sadly, changing the nemo-autostart.desktop as mentioned above, somehow does not work for me. Launching it with GTK_CSD="" nemo from the terminal works fine though.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

### The same in Loki:

Inspired by a comment by [shrestha-aj](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/218/shrestha-aj) under other answer:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false
```

In Dconf Editor:

[image]