# Desktop showing as a window above original

Tags: release-loki, desktop, files, nautilus, show-desktop

I'm running Elementary OS Loki, and recently I've decided to change default file manager to Nemo.

After installing and setting it as default in *System settings > Applications > Default applications*, on each launch of Nemo (either from *.desktop* or CLI) I have a window named "Desktop" which duplicates my original desktop, but isn't responding to anything or closing. The only way is to shut down Nemo, and then `xkill` the window.

I have read before that it is kind of connected to Nautilus and desktop icons, but I have neither Nautilus nor enabled icons in my OS.
Is there a way to fix this, or should I look for another file manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem, the command to hide this window is `gsettings set org.nemo.desktop show-desktop-icons false`.

*EDIT*: And to fix the desktop instead of disabling it, I just followed this guide and everything works: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/3841/7699

Comment: also: http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/10663/170